# client-server fetch large data

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, client-server

I have a application need a list of data, but these data may be very large. If I'm going to show this list of data in client (mobile app), I can't get all of the data from server because the limit space of mobile.

For example, like Facebook app, there are tons of newsfeed in server, and user can only see some of them. If user want to see more, they need to scroll down and fresh. So how to implement something like this in both client and server? (Currently my server is written in ruby on rails, and client is iOS)

And once the client get those data, does it store in memory or in local database? I'm worried about memory limit in mobile phones.

Thanks

Comment: You dont need to worry about the memory, it is not that the data you use is more than 1000 mbs. You get some json from the server and save it in your database. So, go ahead and use core data, that reduces your worries since it is fast enough and efficient for UI.

Comment: you show your data in a uitableView or what ??

Comment: the best way is to load data when you scroll .
give me your email and i will send you an example tomorrow

Comment: @poyofever.Yeah, I will show data in uitableview. bill.snowwolf@gmail.com. Thanks

Comment: thanks i will send you the sample tomorrow afternoon.

Answer (score 1):

On the server-side, you could probably write an API supporting pagination and custom results count, i.e.: `myapp.com/api/get?start=0&count=20` to get the first 20 results, and when the user scrolls all the way down your view on the iPhone, fetch the next items, like that: `myapp.com/api/get?start=20&count=20`.

If you plan your design well, you'll get something very flexible that you'll be able to change later if you realize that 20 results is too much/not enough, etc.

Depending on your app's architecture and the amount of data your app will handle, you might also need to provide API methods based on the last-updated time, to ensure you're not missing data (e.g., if you call your second `get?start=20` a few minutes after the first one, the `start` index might not have the same meaning).

As for storing data locally, it all depends on what you want to achieve. Are you sure you need to save *everything* the user has downloaded? You could store only the most recently fetched items in a local SQLite database and query them the next time your app starts up, before refreshing the view (I don't know how it is implemented in Facebook's iPhone app but at least it looks like it's done that way).